# Why is the login form not logging me in and reloads the login page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I am building a Laravel project and the login form isn't logging me in. I changed the redirect in RouteServiceProvider, but the log in page just keeps reloading. When I register as a user it logs me in, but when I log out and try to log back in, it doesn't work.

RedirectIfAuthenitacted:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

LoginController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Login View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<section class="login-form-container">
    <div class="login-form-inner-container">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/waveHouse-logo.svg') }}" alt="">
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" class="login-form">
            @csrf
            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Email Address') }}</label>
            <input id="email" type="email">

            <label for="password">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Login') }}
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

Comment: please provide the `routes.php` content too.

Comment: your login view or layout should display any session errors if they exist. its possible the login is failing and returning an error but you are not displaying them ... a possible mistake could be double hashing or not hashing the password when you are creating the user (which would make the login fail)

Comment: @lagbox I added the errors on the login blade file and the error is saying email field is required, but I am filling both the email and password input fields.

Comment: you don't have an input **named** 'email' in your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I was missing name from the email input field. I added that in as well as error messages and that did the trick! :)